# Space-efficient algorithm for checking if strings with backspaces are equal?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

I was recently asked this question in an interview:

> Given two strings s and t, return if they are equal when both are
>   typed into empty text editors. # means a backspace character.

```
Input: S = "ab#c", T = "ad#c"
Output: true
Explanation: Both S and T become "ac".
```

I came up with below solution but it is not space efficient:

```
  public static boolean sol(String s, String t) {
    return helper(s).equals(helper(t));
  }

  public static String helper(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
      if (c != '#')
        stack.push(c);
      else if (!stack.empty())
        stack.pop();
    }
    return String.valueOf(stack);
  }
```

I wanted to see if there is any better way to solve this problem which doesn't use stack. I mean can we solve it in O(1) space complexity?

**Note:** we could have multiple backspace characters in as well.

Comment: Are you looking for # or a backspace character?

Comment: Look at my example in the above question, you will understand. It's a backspace character.

Comment: I imagine a regex could remove any character immediately preceding the #

Comment: We need to implement this in traditional way instead of using regex I think.

Comment: In that case, loop through the chars in your String and when you encounter a #, move your index back and skip 2 characters?

Comment: You don't need any extra storage at all to do this. Just the two original strings.

Comment: I think it is possible, but it of want `O(1)` extra storage, you will need `O(N^2)` time.  Computing the `i`th character with no extra storage is `O(N)`.

Comment: @StephenC why O(n^2)? Aren't the two presented answers linear time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala String Equality Question from Programming Interview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241686/scala-string-equality-question-from-programming-interview)

Comment: @wchargin I am not sure that this is duplicate, because the question is specific to `java`, not `scala`.

Comment: @Oleksandr: Both questions are about the algorithm (improving the space complexity). The implementation language is not very relevant; answers from either could easily be translated into the other.

Answer (score 14):

In order to achieve `O(1)` space complexity, use *Two Pointers* and start from the end of the string:

```
public static boolean sol(String s, String t) {
    int i = s.length() - 1;
    int j = t.length() - 1;
    while (i >= 0 || j >= 0) {
        i = consume(s, i);
        j = consume(t, j);
        if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(j)) {
            i--;
            j--;
        } else {
            return i == -1 && j == -1;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The main idea is to maintain the `#` counter: increment `cnt` if character is `#`, otherwise decrement it. And if `cnt > 0` and `s.charAt(pos) != '#'` - skip the character (decrement position):

```
private static int consume(String s, int pos) {
    int cnt = 0;
    while (pos >= 0 && (s.charAt(pos) == '#' || cnt > 0)) {
        cnt += (s.charAt(pos) == '#') ? +1 : -1;
        pos--;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Time complexity: `O(n)`.

<sup>[Source 1](https://leetcode.com/problems/backspace-string-compare/discuss/135603), [Source 2](https://leetcode.com/problems/backspace-string-compare/discuss/162827).</sup>

Comment: Do you know the time complexity of this? My hunch is that while there are two loops now, it is still bounded by the number of backspaces, which in turn is bounded by the combined length of the strings (i.e. linear).

Comment: @Thilo You are right! The time complexity is `O(n)`: the outer `while` loop just passes the responsibility to the inner loop from time to time.

Comment: sol("", "a") will return true in this code.  Perhaps ok for an interview.  Not ok for a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Corrected pseudocode of templatetypedef

```
// Index of next spot to read from each string
let sIndex = s.length() - 1
let tIndex = t.length() - 1
let sSkip = 0
let tSkip = 0

while sIndex >= 0 and tIndex >= 0:
    if s[sIndex] = #:
        sIndex = sIndex - 1
        sSkip = sSkip + 1
        continue
    else if sSkip > 0
        sIndex = sIndex - 1
        sSkip = sSkip - 1
        continue

    // Do the same thing for t.
    if t[tIndex] = #:
        tIndex = tIndex - 1
        tSkip = tSkip + 1
        continue
    else if tSkip > 0
        tIndex = tIndex - 1
        tSkip = tSkip - 1
        continue

    // Compare characters.
    if s[sIndex] != t[tIndex], return false

    // Back up to the next character
    sIndex = sIndex - 1
    tIndex = tIndex - 1

// The strings match if we’ve exhausted all characters.
return sIndex < 0 and tIndex < 0
```